# Using R Caret model with different tunning parameters

Tags: r, r-caret

I trained a NNET Caret Model with three sizes in tuning function.
The final Model was fitted with one size. It was choosed by the smallest RMSE, automatically.

```
    Neural Network 

9700 samples
  23 predictor

Pre-processing: centered, scaled 
Resampling: Cross-Validated (8 fold, repeated 8 times) 

Summary of sample sizes: 8488, 8488, 8487, 8485, 8488, 8488, ... 

Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  size  RMSE    Rsquared  RMSE SD   Rsquared SD
  12    0.0328  0.951     0.002033  0.006127   
  24    0.0221  0.978     0.001358  0.002764   
  72    0.0134  0.992     0.000647  0.000815   

Tuning parameter 'decay' was held constant at a value of 5e-04
RMSE was used to select the optimal model using  the smallest value.
The final values used for the model were size = 72 and decay = 5e-04.
```

But I want to explore the models trained with the others sizes too.
Can I use the the predict function with others tunning parameters of the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `savePredictions` argument of `trainControl`, you can get the hold-out predictions from the different models in the tuning grid. Apart from that, you would need to fit separate models.

Max

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Unfortunately I didn't know this function. So, I'll need to fit this again.